# Why are UIButton actions not being called when UIButton is inside a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have created a springboard like panel containing buttons as follows:

```
-(void)configurePanel{

self.criteriaPanel.scrollEnabled=YES;
self.criteriaPanel=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(
                                                                0.0f, 
                                                                0.0f, 
                                                                [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,
                                                                (BUTTON_HEIGHT+(3*BUTTON_Y_OFFSET))
                                                                )];

UIView *scrollViewContent=[[UIView alloc]init];
NSArray *criteriaTypeButtonTitles=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 @"Option1",
                                 @"Option2",
                                 @"Option3",
                                 @"Option4",
                                 @"Option5",
                                 @"Option6",
                                 nil
                                 ];

for (int i=0; i<[criteriaTypeButtonTitles count]; i++) {
  UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  button.tag=i;
  button.frame = CGRectMake(
                          (((BUTTON_X_OFFSET*i)+(BUTTON_WIDTH*i))+BUTTON_X_OFFSET)
                          , BUTTON_Y_OFFSET
                          , BUTTON_WIDTH
                          , BUTTON_HEIGHT
                          );  
  [button setTitle:[criteriaTypeButtonTitles objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
  button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f];
  [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
  [button.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
  [button.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(sortByButtonTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
  [scrollViewContent addSubview:button];
}

//based upon # of buttons
self.criteriaPanel.contentSize=CGSizeMake(
                                        (([criteriaTypeButtonTitles count]*BUTTON_WIDTH)+([criteriaTypeButtonTitles count]*BUTTON_X_OFFSET)),
                                        (BUTTON_HEIGHT+(2*BUTTON_Y_OFFSET)));
[self.criteriaPanel addSubview:scrollViewContent];
[self.view addSubview:self.criteriaPanel];
}
```

The panel displays correctly and scrolls, but the tap events (sortByButtonTap:) for the buttons are never called. I suspect this is related to the buttons being contained in a view which is contained in the scrollview. After reading a number of other questions and the docs I still can't figure out what the solution should be.

EDIT:
I experimented w/ adding the buttons to the UIScrollView (self.criteriaPanel) directly and the button taps call sortByButtonTap: so it is something to do w/ the buttons being in the scrollViewContent.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please mark the correct answer to mark this post as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set `userInteractionEnabled` on the containing view `scrollViewContent` for the button to receive touch events:

```
[scrollViewContent setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not cause the action method to be called. I also, tried it in combination w/ the suggestion by demon8733.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(sortByButtonTap:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

try:

```
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(sortByButtonTap:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not cause the action method to be called. I also, tried it in combination w/ the suggestion by gregheo.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try:

```
[button setExclusiveTouch:YES];
```

Buttons tend to work abnormally when they are inside a view that also handles touch events.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code for your query,

Add UIButton in Scrollview

```
    scrollview.pagingEnabled = YES;
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake();
    [button setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCloseClicked:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCloseDraged:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCloseDragedEnd:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
    [scrollview addSubview:button];
    scrollview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

you can put this three methods of button manually.

Let me know if you still have query.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is just that you set the wrong `UIControlEvent` to the `UIButton`. Change from `UIControlEventTouchDown` to `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. If you connect a `UIButton` inside the `Interface Builder` it will always set it to this `UIControlEvent`:

[image]

Another reason:

Otherwise your `UIScrollView` controls the interactions because it needs to know if you want to scroll it. If you place `UIButtons` inside your `UIScrollView` they will be accessible but always with a little delay. This is why you should maybe change the settings for the `UIScrollView`:

You can disable `delays content touches` and `UIButtons` will be accessible immediately

[image]